# How can I accept packages?

Tags: linux-kernel

Running the following code,I want to accept IP packets are defined but dropping all packets.. where is the my error? please help me

```
 struct iphdr* iph = ip_hdr(skb);
 struct sk_buff *sb = *skb;

 struct in_addr masterIP;

 masterIP.s_addr = htonl (in_aton("192.168.1.10")); 
 iph->saddr = masterIP.s_addr;
 return NF_ACCEPT;
```